# Sonar Squid Error while sonar analysis with jenkins job through maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using jenkins for continous integration build process through maven and using sonar for code review as well. jenkins job is working fine for creating build but when sonar analysis starts, it throw below error..

```
[ERROR] [19:19:47.494] Squid Error occurs when analysing :D:\Jenkins_New\jobs\Sample_Maven_Project\workspace\src\main\java\software\bean\UserBean.java
```

`org.sonar.squid.api.AnalysisException:` The source directory does not correspond to the package declaration software.bean
"
I'm stucked in this issue.

below is my project `pom.xml` file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nuc</groupId>
    <artifactId>nuc</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>nuc</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>neutrino-central-repository-Nexus</id>
            <name>Neutrino Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://10.1.50.56:9081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>neutrino-central-plugin-repository-Nexus</id>
            <url>http://10.1.50.56:9081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>WebContent</directory>
                <targetPath>/${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</targetPath> 
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>



            <resource>
                <directory>src/META-INF</directory>
                <targetPath>/${project.build.directory}/META-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What's the reason behind defining `source directory` and `resource directory` to the same `src` directory?

Comment: thanks charlee for your input, i am able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the ".java" source files are not located in a correct folder.

If your project is a Maven project, chances are that the ".java" source files are located in `<project>/src/main/java` - like the convention suggests it.

However, from what I see in your POM, you have set the source folder to be "src" instead of "src/main/java". This is why you get this error.